# Best way to catch Low State of GPIO in an endless script

Tags: raspberry-pi, interrupt, gpio

Can you please tell me what's the best way to catch a low state (or falling-edge more precisely) of **GPIO** in an endless script? 
To be clear I will run this **script at boot** (in the bg) and everytime when a user will push a button (connected to this **GPIO**) this will put this pin at **LOW state**. I want to detect each one of them and perform actions at every push.
I already have this code but it will consume to much **CPU** I think... I need sth like an interrupt in my mind :

```
import RPi.GPIO as GPIO

#Set GPIO numbering scheme to pinnumber
GPIO.setmode(GPIO.BCM)
#setup pin 4 as an input
GPIO.setup(4,GPIO.IN)

# To read the state
While true:
   state = GPIO.input(4)
   if state:
      print('on')
   else:
      print('off')
```

**EDIT**

[Here the pinout by BCM or BOARD, I will work with BCM](https://i.stack.imgur.com/8ZR2x.png)

As you can the the pin number is 4 because my push button is on GPIO4.
Still get off all the time with your code or constant detection of edge event with the code of **@jp-jee**

**EDIT**

```
#!/usr/bin/env python3
import time
import RPi.GPIO as GPIO

GPIO.setmode(GPIO.BCM)
GPIO.setup(4,GPIO.IN)

def Callback(channel):
      print('pushed')

GPIO.add_event_detect(4, GPIO.FALLING, callback = Callback, bouncetime = 300)

while(True):
   time.sleep(1)
```

Now my code print always pushed when the button is released and print nothing when I push it...

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Take a look at [the documentation of raspberry-gpio-python](https://sourceforge.net/p/raspberry-gpio-python/wiki/Inputs/).

What you want is `GPIO.add_event_detect(channel, GPIO.RISING)` in combination with a callback function.
Since you're using a button, you also need to consider bouncing.

In the end, you will end up with something like this (taken from the linked website):

```
def my_callback(channel):
    print('This is a edge event callback function!')

GPIO.add_event_detect(channel, GPIO.FALLING, callback=my_callback, bouncetime=200)
```

Comment: tried sth like this before and with your code the program run and end without any errors or print (within 2 seconds)

Comment: You have de keep the main thread running, e.g. with an infinite loop.

Answer (score 0):

Have you tried to use interrupts?

```
import time
import RPi.GPIO as GPIO

GPIO.setup(4, GPIO.IN)

def Callback(channel):
   state = GPIO.input(channel)
   if state:
      print('on')
   else:
      print('off')

GPIO.add_event_detect(4, GPIO.FALLING, callback = Callback, bouncetime = 300)  

while(True):
   time.sleep(1)
```

Comment: All the time on off with this code...(I add "GPIO.setmode(GPIO.BCM)" just before GPIO.setup(4, GPIO.IN))

Comment: So maybe the GPIO number is not the right one. `GPIO.BCM` means that you use the GPIO 4 of the processor, which is pin 8 of the header in the versions B+, 2B, Zero and 3B.
Are you sure that the GPIO is the right one and the button is connected right? My example use a button without external pull up, which is tied to ground when you press it. Or you can increase the parameter `bouncetime` to configure your debounce. `bouncetime` means that the event can only be triggered every x miliseconds.

Comment: Ok I get it i have a prob with my push button...Resolved now. See my 2nd Edit.

Comment: Do you use a pull-up resistor for the pin with the push button? You need to set the pin to a fixed level if you don´t press the button (and this level has to be Vcc, because your switch ties to ground). Otherwise you get a floating voltage level on that pin, which produce this kind of error. If you don´t have an external pull up, set one in [software](https://raspi.tv/2013/rpi-gpio-basics-6-using-inputs-and-outputs-together-with-rpi-gpio-pull-ups-and-pull-downs).

Comment: Exactly that was the problem... Basic one but hopefully you're here for remind me, Thx !